# PHP / MYSQL generalise SELECT clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generalise a Select query using checkboxes, the varible choice you will see is posted from a front end file which uses checkboxes to create an array in the back end. This array is then used to for the SELECT clause of a select statement. Currently the table head outputs the correct header however the data also outputs the same data. Can anyone help me find my error.

```
<?php
session_start(); //Begins a session
?>

<html> <head> <title> Genre selection back end </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$genre_value =  $_POST['genrelist'];

$choice = $_POST['choice'];

$numvalues = count($choice);
echo '<h2> Table shows some data </h2>';
echo "<table border = '1'>";
echo '<tr>';

for($i= 0; $i < $numvalues; $i ++)
{
echo "<th>" .$choice[$i]. "</th>";
$choicearray = $choicearray . ", " .  $choice[$i];
}
echo '</tr>';

$select = substr($choicearray, 1);
include '../functions/connect.php';
$query = "SELECT '$select' FROM film WHERE Genre = '".$genre_value."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Invalid query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
        for($i = 0; $i < $numvalues; $i ++)
        {
        echo "<td>" .$row[$i]. "</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say 'the data also outputs the same data' what exactly do you mean?  Are you getting a result but every row is identical or are you just repeating the header row over and over?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem .. can you show us an example?

Comment: Say if my choice is release date, I would get a header as a release date, header would then close. Table data would also be release date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single quotes in your select statement.  That makes MySQL select those exact string values.

Remove the single quotes. Change your query to

```
$query = "SELECT $select FROM film WHERE Genre = '".$genre_value."'";
```

Also, please don't use this code for anything more than proof on concept.  You absolutely must never trust `POST` or `GET` data directly in a query.  Make sure you escape each of those values first.

I'd suggest you change your for loop to something like this:

```
$choicearray = array();
for($i= 0; $i < $numvalues; $i ++)
{
    echo "<th>" .$choice[$i]. "</th>";
    $choicearray[] = mysql_escape_string(trim($choice[$i]));
}
echo '</tr>';
$choicearray = implode(',', $choicearray);
```

Which will give you the same result but escape every item along the way.

Comment: That now brings up an invalid query, going to check my front end to make sure the checkbox values matches what is in the db

Comment: Check with an echo or var_dump that $choicearray is really what you want it to be, and that all of the columns are real columns in your table.

For instance, make sure that if $choicearray is 'id, name, value' that all three of those are in your film table.

Comment: btw. `$query = "SELECT $select FROM film WHERE Genre = '$genre_value'";` no need for concat there.

Comment: Shomz is absolutely right, it's more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Ok, Ive made all changes and checked with the db, query not works, thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Can you echo out the query that is being generated and post it? Also the error that you're getting?